# Grails - find which jar(s) have a class

Tags: grails, jar

Is there any way I can find out which Jars have a particular class file in my grails project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the java way to do this:

```
Class cls = YourClass.class;
CodeSource cs = cls.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
System.out.println("YourClass is in this jar file: "+ cs);
```

[CodeSource JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html)